# DOS [like] operating systems parts and specification

Tags: operating-system, dos

What are the DOS-like operating systems parts and their specifications?

For example:

MS-DOS:

1. Kernel Design: blah blah blah
2. File System: blah blah blah
3. Bootloader: ...
4. ...

86-DOS:

1. ...
2. ...

Multiuser DOS:

1. ...

and so on.

P.S. I'm interested to know about all the versions, so feel free to share your knowledge about any of list or unlisted versions.

Comment: Well, MS-DOS is very different from a linux without graphic interface. Incredibly different. And answering your question about components and specifications would require a book.. or two. What exactly are you interested in?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start (*with a huge list*):

[Comparison of DOS operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_DOS_operating_systems) and some of their technical specifications (*on wikipedia*)

They talk about:

- PC-DOS
- MS-DOS
- Z-DOS
- DOS PLUS
- DR DOS
- Caldera OpenDOS
- FreeDos

etc.

Here are more informations on the [system components of MS-DOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS), including design, boot system, file system, drive naming scheme, memory management, etc.

There is also an extensive [Comparison of operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_operating_systems) on wikipedia, with some technical information…